Comptonization of CMB photons by AGN jets: Theoretical possibility of visible light emission?"
Theoretically, can the Comptonization of Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) photons by energetic electrons in Active Galactic Nuclei (AGN) jets result in the emission of visible light?
If so, what are the specific conditions required for this process to occur, and what would be the expected characteristics of the emitted visible light?
Has this process been observed or constrained by any existing observations or experiments?
